# Automapper IList - Signature of the body and declaration in a method implementation do not match

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, automapper, dto, ilist

I have this mapping defined in my Application Layer:

```
public IList<ProfessionDTO> GetAllProfessions()
{
    IList<Profession> professions = _professionRepository.GetAll();
    Mapper.CreateMap<Profession, ProfessionDTO>();
    Mapper.CreateMap<IList<Profession>, IList<ProfessionDTO>>();
    IList<ProfessionDTO> professionsDto = Mapper.Map<IList<Profession>, IList<ProfessionDTO>>(professions);
    return professionsDto;
}
```

**Proffesion entity**

```
 public class Profession
    {
        private int _id;
        private string _name;


        private Profession(){} // required by nHibernate

        public Profession(int id, string name)
        {
            ParameterValidator.NotNull(id, "id is required.");
            ParameterValidator.NotNull(name, "name is required.");
            _id = id;
            _name = name;
        }

        public string Name
        {
            get { return _name; }
        }

        public int Id
        {
            get { return _id; }
        }
    }
```

**Profession DTO:**

```
public class ProfessionDTO
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

When executing **GetAllProfessions** I get this error:

**Signature of the body and declaration in a method implementation do not match.**

Any idea why is it happening?

I have just changed all the IList to List. I don't get the exception now but the List of 27 entities of Profession that is retrieved is mapped to 0 of ProfessionDTO.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I feel silly answering my own question.

I don't need this line:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<IList<Profession>, IList<ProfessionDTO>>();
```

Now Auomapper works perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

you don't have setters for your Id and Name attribute in your profession class.

Comment: It shouldn't matter. Profession entity is the source. Setters are never used.

Comment: Yeah, I know, but it is the only thing I see different between those properties..

Answer (score 0):

The answer indicated seems wrong;
Correct one should be like;

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Profession, ProfessionDTO>();
```